# How to OR when capturing multiple webdriver exceptions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to capture multiple exceptions like this but I get error `'); expected'`. How do I do it using `||`?

```
   try {
         //find an element here
    }catch( StaleElementReferenceException e || NoSuchElementException e) {
        //do something            
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java 7, you should be able to use this syntax:

```
catch (StaleElementReferenceException | NoSuchElementException e)
```

Note the *single* `|`, as well as the single variable name.

See the ["Catching Multiple Exception Types And Rethrowing Exceptions With Improved Type Checking"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) doc for more details (catchy title, huh?).

If you're not using Java 7, you'll need multiple `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
try {
  //find an element here
 }catch( StaleElementReferenceException e){
  // do something    
 }catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
  //do something            
 }
```

Note: The **second catch blocks must catch broader or newer exception** or else the code will not compile.